# How to get the cursor positioned correclty when placing a CKEditor inline widget on a line by itself

Tags: ckeditor

On reload of the CKEditor with an inline Widget, when clicking into the editor on the same line as the widget, the cursor is positioned at the end of the line.

The issue occurs when an inline widget is placed on a line without any other content.  I've tried changing the structure of the html, adding styles, and adding an extra space in the parent span. Nothing has worked so far.

You can see this issue here: [https://ckeditorexample.herokuapp.com](https://ckeditorexample.herokuapp.com/)

Widget SDK http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_intro

Source code for the widget:

```js
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('mywidget', {
    requires: 'widget',
    icons: 'mywidget',
    init: function (editor) {
        editor.widgets.add('mywidget', {
            button: 'Create a simple box',
            // draggable:true,
            inline: true,
            template: '<span class="mywidget">' +
            '<span class="mywidget-content" >....</span>' +
            '</span>',
            allowedContent: {
                'span': {
                    // propertiesOnly: true,
                    classes: '*'
                }
            },
            requiredContent: 'span(mywidget)',
            init: function () {

            },
            upcast: function (element) {
                return element.name == 'span' && element.hasClass('mywidget');
            },
            data: function () {
                if (this.data.name) {
                    $(this.element.$).find('.mywidget-content').html(this.data.name);
                }
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: +1

same issue here...

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if the cursor is being sent to the end of the containing `<p>...</p>`.

In my particular case (via a different effort), I ended up needing to change the default enterMode.  To allow for single-spaced text in my forms I changed the default ENTER_P value to ENTER_BR:

enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR

After I did this, **the issue went away**, as there was no longer a paragraph to move the cursor to the end of.  I'll take it...  ;-)